# jQuery/Javascript code not working after reload (Pixel Color Detection)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, pixel, color-picker

I'm using a code that detects the color of a pixel on click, it works well... But, after reload the webpage, it stops working, I saw a strange behaviors it looks that the Script is added to the DOM after load it. Can you help me?

```js
<script>

function rgbaToHex (r,g,b,a) {
    return ('#' + r.toString(16) + g.toString(16) + b.toString(16) + (a * 255).toString(16).substring(0,2));
}

(function($){
 $.fn.canvasify = function(f){ // faster than dynamically converting a pixel at a time
  return this.map(function(){
   if (this.nodeName=="IMG"){
    var canvas=$('<canvas>');
    this.src = this.src; // IE fix
    $(this).one('load',function(){
     canvas.attr({width:this.width,height:this.height});
     canvas[0].getContext('2d').drawImage(this,0,0,this.width,this.height);
     $(this).replaceWith(canvas);
    })
    return canvas[0];
   }else{
    return this;
   }
  })
 }
 function Rgba(rgba){
  this.rgba = rgba;
  this.toString = function(){ return "rgba("+Array.prototype.join.call(this.rgba,',')+")" };
 }
 $.Event.prototype.rgba=function(){
  var x =  this.offsetX || (this.pageX - $(this.target).offset().left),
   y =  this.offsetY || (this.pageY - $(this.target).offset().top),
   nodeName = this.target.nodeName
  if (nodeName==="CANVAS")
   return new Rgba(this.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(x,y,1,1).data);
  else if (nodeName==="IMG"){
   var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
   canvas.width=1;
   canvas.height=1;
   canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this.target,x,y,1,1,0,0,1,1);
   return new Rgba(canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0,0,1,1).data);
  } else return null;
 }
})(jQuery)
 jQuery(function() {
   jQuery('#ImgMap').children('img').eq(0).canvasify().live("click", demo);
   function demo(e){
   var rgba = e.rgba();
   var hex = rgbaToHex(rgba.rgba[0],rgba.rgba[1],rgba.rgba[2],rgba.rgba[3]);
   if(hex == "#f38567fe") {
    console.log("Orange");
    var htmlString = '<h1 style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="color: #20587e;">Orange</span></strong></h1> <p style="text-align: center;">Orange Orange.</p> <p style="text-align: center;">This also means they can be difficult to pronounce for beginners.</p>';
    jQuery("#Text_Country").html(htmlString);
   }
   if(hex == "#737097fe") {
    console.log("Purple");
    var htmlString = '<h1 style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="color: #20587e;">Purple</span></strong></h1> <p style="text-align: center;">Orange Orange.</p> <p style="text-align: center;">This also means they can be difficult to pronounce for beginners.</p>';
    jQuery("#Text_Country").html(htmlString);
   }
   if(hex == "#68c08cfe") {
    console.log("Green");
    var htmlString = '<h1 style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="color: #20587e;">Green</span></strong></h1> <p style="text-align: center;">Orange Orange.</p> <p style="text-align: center;">This also means they can be difficult to pronounce for beginners.</p>';
    jQuery("#Text_Country").html(htmlString);
   }
   if(hex == "#ffe275fe") {
    console.log("Yellow");
    var htmlString = '<h1 style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="color: #20587e;">Yellow</span></strong></h1> <p style="text-align: center;">Orange Orange.</p> <p style="text-align: center;">This also means they can be difficult to pronounce for beginners.</p>';
    jQuery("#Text_Country").html(htmlString);
   }
   //console.log(rgba.rgba[0]);
   //console.log(e);
    //console.log(rgbaToHex(rgba.rgba[0],rgba.rgba[1],rgba.rgba[2],rgba.rgba[3]));
  }
 });
 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

after search in Internet, the trick was in using this portion of code

jQuery("#ImgMap").unbind( "click" );
jQuery('#ImgMap').children('img').eq(0).canvasify().click(demo);

also delete the line of code:

jQuery(function() {

I hope it will be useful for somebody else.

Thanks